# What is the best way to have my server facilitate a wire transfer?

Tags: node.js, currency, banking

What is the best way to have my server facilitate a wire transfer?

It's for writing a program to pay out from my bank account to others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ask your bank if they have InterBank Fund Transfer facility(such as via ATM or internet banking). If they have it, you wont need to write that program anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the country you are in, but to my knowledge there aren't any banks that have an API to send payment requests. You can however create a batch file with all the pay outs and upload this in the online environment of your bank. You will contact your local bank for instructions about the format and process.